# Cells in UITableView keep clear when searching in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have got an application which has a `UITableView` containing two sections. Now I wanted to add a `UISearchBar` to allow searching. And the searching really works pretty fine and selects the correct cells. When searching you can see that there are cells you can select, but the labels are blank. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"qrCodeCell";
    QRTableViewCell *cell = (QRTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[QRTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            //NSLog(@"%@",[[self.searchResultsQR objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"data"]);
            [cell.dataLabel setText:[[self.searchResultsQR objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"data"]];
            //NSLog(@"%@",cell.dataLabel.text);

            NSDate *timeStamp = [[self.searchResultsQR objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
            [cell.timeLabel setText:[format stringFromDate:timeStamp]];
        } else {
            [cell.dataLabel setText:[[self.qrcodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"data"]];
            NSDate *timeStamp = [[self.qrcodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
            [cell.timeLabel setText:[format stringFromDate:timeStamp]];
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            [cell.dataLabel setText:[[self.searchResultsScanned objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"data"]];
            NSDate *timeStamp = [[self.searchResultsScanned objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
            [cell.timeLabel setText:[format stringFromDate:timeStamp]];
        } else {
            [cell.dataLabel setText:[[self.scannedCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"data"]];
            NSDate *timeStamp = [[self.scannedCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
            [cell.timeLabel setText:[format stringFromDate:timeStamp]];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This is pretty much exactly the same issue as in these questions, but the problem could not be resolved: [UISearchBar with UITableView containing custom cells => blank cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520382/uisearchbar-with-uitableview-containing-custom-cells-blank-cells) and [It doesn't show the contents of the cells in a UITableView filtered by a UISearchDisplayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419765/it-doesnt-show-the-contents-of-the-cells-in-a-uitableview-filtered-by-a-uisearc)

I would really appreciate if someone can help me!

**EDIT:**

Here is some more code from my `TableViewController`:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"data contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResultsQR = [self.qrcodes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    self.searchResultsScanned = [self.scannedCodes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you returning the correct number of rows when searching and also confirm what are the values in the array when you are searching?

Comment: Yes, this part works perfectly. As you can see in my code I checked this via `NSLog` and then whether it has been written into the label, but it has not.

Comment: Can you please also share the code written in searchDisplayController Delegate

Comment: Last thing are you using storyboards or xib?

Comment: I am using storyboards. My tableViewController is the delegate, so I will add the methods to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell is not registered properly. This means that your code will run:

```
cell = [[QRTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

which will not create all of your subviews or connect any of the outlets.

You need to find out why your cell isn't registered properly. If you created it in a storyboard then it should be contained in the table view where it will be used (which should automatically register the cell). If you created it in a standalone XIB file then you need to load the NIB and register it explicitly when the table view is loaded.

You have 2 table views, the cell is registered with one but not the other - this is the way prototype cells work.

Your best options:

-Remove the prototype cell, create an XIB and register the NIB with each table view explicitly

-Not to use a search controller (so you only have 1 table view, manage the search bar yourself)

[These are a few references which you can look forward to.](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook/blob/master/C11/06-Searching%20Tables/main.m)

[This is a tutorial for implementing search delgates with storyboard](http://www.brennablackwell.com/?p=83)

Also found a discussion on SO which might give you some direction of where you are going wrong

[Search Bar in UITableView doesn't display text in Cell label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809863/search-bar-in-uitableview-doesnt-display-text-in-cell-label)

Comment: While debugging everything carefully, I mentioned that there has been very much not the way it should be (e.g. the cell became nil suddenly). But when taking your advice outsourcing the cell into a separate XIB file, everything works like a charm now! Very thank you!!